# How to remove contact from device in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to remove all contacts from the device from my application in Blacberry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this functionality in my application with this following code.

```
try {
BlackBerryPIM pim = (BlackBerryPIM) BlackBerryPIM.getInstance();
BlackBerryContactList contactList = (BlackBerryContactList) pim
            .openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
Enumeration enumer = contactList.items();
while (enumer.hasMoreElements()) {
BlackBerryContact contact = (BlackBerryContact) enumer.nextElement();
    contactList.removeContact(contact);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
}
```